# Find count of unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which has these columns: id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id, r and flag.

In which each row with these values should be unique and not duplicated.

I want to write a query in which i find if this set (id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id) is unique or not. and if its unique then column flag = 0 otherwise flag = 1.

for example:

```
auto_id      id                   p_id  s_id    c_id    cr_id   r   flag
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
10591   SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt   1   29      NULL    14      3   NULL
10596   SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt   1   29      NULL    46      3   NULL
10601   SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt   1   29      NULL    47      3   NULL 
10606   SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt   1   29      NULL    12      3   NULL
10611   SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt   1   29      NULL    43      3   NULL
```

this is unique not duplicated and flag should be 0

the other case is when:

```
auto_id      id                    p_id s_id    c_id    cr_id   r   flag
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
10614   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       11     3    NULL
10619   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       22     3    NULL
10624   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       23     4    NULL
10629   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       24     3    NULL
10634   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       11     3    NULL
10639   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       22     3    NULL
10644   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       23     4    NULL
10649   jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G   1   6       3       24     3    NULL
```

in this case flag should be 1

i don't want to include r in the query since it could be different.. the unique should be a combination of id, p_id, s_id, c_id and cr_id

How can i write such a query?

Comment: Please add sample data in tabular format rather than Image. Also there are issue defining the column names in the image.

Comment: @mkRabbani how to insert as table?

Comment: Just use 4 spaces before each line. Try it, hope you will learn it soon as its so easy :) @Lama

Comment: You forgot the headers of the columns.

Comment: @forpas updated please check

Comment: Do you want unique rows only in the final result?

Comment: Is auto_id unique?

Comment: @Samir i want if its a unique row then set flag to 0 , otherwise set it to 1

Comment: @forpas yes its a auto increment id

Comment: I understood that, but in the final result do you need unique values only or you need all rows with duplicates and an identifier whether it is unique or not?

Comment: If the sample id was, say, 3 characters instead of 20, would it make the question any less comprehensible?

Comment: @Samir i want all and the flag will be the identifier if 0 then unique and 1 duplicate

Comment: @Samir am doing this to clean the data

Comment: So, you want to delete duplicate rows from the table and maintain one unique entry for each.

Comment: @Samir yes exactly, but soft delete them by using flag column

Comment: Auto id is also unique. Should auto_id also excluded as R?

Comment: @mkRabbani auto_id shouldn't be included in the set to determine replicas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to the table a subquery that counts the repeated rows:

```
select t.*, (g.counter > 1) flag 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id
) g on g.id = t.id and g.p_id = t.p_id and g.s_id = t.s_id and coalesce(g.c_id, 0) = coalesce(t.c_id, 0) and g.cr_id = t.cr_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8VwDQMQK3T5SPRVjrtfJk/0).
If you want to update the column flag in the table:

```
update tablename t inner join (
  select id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id
) g on g.id = t.id and g.p_id = t.p_id and g.s_id = t.s_id and coalesce(g.c_id, 0) = coalesce(t.c_id, 0) and g.cr_id = t.cr_id
set t.flag = (g.counter > 1);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8VwDQMQK3T5SPRVjrtfJk/1).
Results:

```
| auto_id | id                        | p_id | s_id | c_id | cr_id | r   | flag |
| ------- | ------------------------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----- | --- | ---- |
| 10591   | SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt | 1    | 29   |      | 14    | 3   | 0    |
| 10596   | SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt | 1    | 29   |      | 46    | 3   | 0    |
| 10601   | SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt | 1    | 29   |      | 47    | 3   | 0    |
| 10606   | SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt | 1    | 29   |      | 12    | 3   | 0    |
| 10611   | SMDLQXQOpxAzIpBesNdrFqXPt | 1    | 29   |      | 43    | 3   | 0    |
| 10614   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 11    | 3   | 1    |
| 10619   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 22    | 3   | 1    |
| 10624   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 23    | 4   | 1    |
| 10629   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 24    | 3   | 1    |
| 10634   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 11    | 3   | 1    |
| 10639   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 22    | 3   | 1    |
| 10644   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 23    | 4   | 1    |
| 10649   | jHkS3ick9g4RnCNnQrwB7VH7G | 1    | 6    | 3    | 24    | 3   | 1    |
```

Comment: i got nothing running this query

Comment: Is there a way to keep one flag =0 if duplicated and others flag = 1?

Comment: @Lama if you have another requirement, post another question and explain there with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the problem, you could simply left join the table with itself and check if, after the join, rows were joined or not.

I will call your table my_table for an example.

```
    select a.*, b.id as b_id 
    from my_table a left join my_table b 
    on a.id = b.id and a.p_id = b.p_id and a.s_id = b.s_id and a.c_id = b.c_id
```

Now, in this select, if b_id is null, the row is unique. If is not null instead, there's a duplicate row. You could use this in your update query, such as:

```
    update my_table
    set flag = 1
    from my_table a left join my_table b 
    on a.id = b.id and a.p_id = b.p_id and a.s_id = b.s_id and a.c_id = b.c_id
    where b.id is not NULL
```

And a similar one setting flag to 0 where b.id is NULL.

Comment: they are all in one table.. why from my_table a left join my_table b  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery :

```
select id, p_id, s_id, c_id, cr_id,
       case when (select count(*) 
                    from my_table 
                   where id=t.id 
                     and p_id=t.p_id 
                     and s_id=t.s_id 
                     and c_id=t.c_id
                     and cr_id=t.cr_id)=1 then
       0
       else
       1
       end flag
  from my_table t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a5da4275a3550b7c755d28f442f815de)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To soft delete duplicate rows from the table, you can simply join the same table and based on auto increment ID delete the remaining ones, while retaining one entry

```
UPDATE my_table t1, my_table t2
SET t1.flag = 1
WHERE t1.auto_id > t2.auto_id
AND t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.p_id = t2.p_id
AND t1.s_id = t2.s_id
AND t1.c_id <=> t2.c_id
AND t1.cr_id = t2.cr_id
```

This query will update all duplicate rows with flag as 1 and retain the one with the lowest `auto_id`. The ones with default value `NULL` are unique ones.
Alternatively, you can alter the table and set default value as 0 for `flag` column.

Please note, the sample data set you provided has c_id as `NULL`. To enable `NULL-safe comparison <=>` is used. If there is any other column with `NULL` value, use `<=>` operator for comparison in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this option-

```
SELECT id,p_id,s_id,c_id,cr_id,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Flag_new
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id,p_id,s_id,c_id,cr_id
```

Comment: this gives duplicated rows merged in only one line for each group.